# Popup menu using ABS

Tags: android, popup, actionbarsherlock, popupmenu

Is it possible to have POPUP menu like play store attached to each row of adapter 
what i done so far

```
holder.rl_overflow.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu(context, holder.rl_overflow);
                popup.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.overflow, popup.getMenu());  

                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new PopupMenu.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {
                        Toast.makeText(context,"You Clicked : " + item.getTitle(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        return false;
                    }
                });
                popup.show();

            }
        });
```

but constructor for POPUP menu says its available from API 11. I go through the developers.android.com and i found, its can be added using SUPPORT V7 library "https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/PopupMenu.html" but i'm not able to implement this using ABS, please help someone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use like this `PopupMenu` in [ActionBarSherlock](https://github.com/mihirjoshi21/ActionBarSherlock).

Styling of the `PopupMenu` -

```
<item name="popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.MyAppTheme</item>      

<style name="PopupMenu.MyAppTheme" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Comment: is this forked version implemented POPUPMENU ?

Comment: i've implemented & tested it successfully

Comment: how to add this style to `PopupMenu` in the class

Answer (score 1):

If you are **using the support library you should discard using the ABS**. Instead, import the support library into your workspace which can be found in `~/adt-bundle-linux-x86_64-20130729/sdk/extras/android/support/v7/appcompact` and use is in your project. And also don't forget to add the `support library` which can be brought up right clicking into your project and entering `Android Tools -> Add Support Library`

Using `appcompact` you will have to extend your activity class with `ActionBarActivity`. And also using the `appcompact` you have to make changes in your `styles` folder. You could refer to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Adding). Do not also forget to update the `values-v11` and `values-v14` file. Doing all of this will make your application compatible.

P.S. If any error occurs in your `appcompact` library. Don't panic look at the error logs and open the file that seems to contain the error. Most probably you will have to refresh the file and after that you just `fix project properties`, and the error goes away.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: i can't switch to appcompact caoz i have many design issues with it, i'm forced to stuck to ABS anyways thanks for suggestion.